# Opening new tab from string url

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So I'm trying to open a new tab on Chrome where the URL is a string. I'm doing it this way because neither Action Chains or Keys seem to work. The purpose of this code is to open a new tab from a selected element but I can't seem to open a new page with the correct website.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import random

chromedriver = "\Program Files\webdrivers/chromedriver"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

driver.get("https://google.com")

time.sleep(3)

for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="prm"]/div/a'):
    A = str(a.get_attribute('href'))
    driver.execute_script("window.open('A');")
```

Comment: Is the xpath correct for the given url [google.com]? could not locate any such locator.

Comment: It is from the dutch google website but you can use any valid xpath. I just looking to make it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open the *hrefs* in seperate *TABs* the correct syntax would be:

```
for a in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="prm"]/div/a'):
    A = str(a.get_attribute('href'))
    driver.execute_script("window.open('" + A +"');")
```

Comment: Is there a way to close that same tab and return to the initial? This is, without closing the whole browser?

Comment: @LourençoSaint-Maurice Of-coarse there is a much **cleaner** way to close the newly opened tab and retain focus on the initial tab without closing the whole browser.

Answer (score 1):

You are opening a new window with the URL of 'A'. It's being treated as a string because you aren't passing in the variable, just a letter. Try

```
driver.execute_script("window.open(arguments[0]);", A)
```

Comment: I accidentally left in the single quotes around `arguments[0]`. I've updated the answer... it works now.